# SignalR : Using base type messages between client and hub

Tags: signalr

I'm fairly new to SignalR so I will try to be as clear as possible.Here is what I'm trying to accomplish :

```
1.Create self-hosted web application using SignalR
2.Create WPF rich client which will communicate with above-mentioned server app.
3.Use strongly typed request/response messages which inherit from base types respectively to pass data from client to server and vice-versa.
```

Here are some definitions of my request/response messages :

```
//Base request message
public class HubRequestMessageBase
{

}

//Base response message
public class HubResponseMessageBase
{
    public bool Success { get; set; }
    public Exception Error { get; set; }
}

//Request message to query node by name
public class QueryNodeRequest : HubRequestMessageBase
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Guid Identifier { get; set; }
}

//Response message carrying metadata for the specified node
public class QueryNodeResponse : HubResponseMessageBase
{
   public NodeMetadata NodeMetadata { get; set; }
}
```

Now, if I define on of my server methods as follows :

```
//Main method for handling client requests
public void HandleClientRequest(HubRequestMessageBase message)
{
    //Omitted for brevity
}
```

and call server method from client like this :

```
internal async void QueryNode(string name)
{
    QueryNodeRequest req = new QueryNodeRequest();
    req.Name = name;

    await HubProxy.Invoke("HandleClientRequest", new object[] { req });
}
```

on the server side, I still get **HubRequestMessageBase** as type of **message** parameter inside **HandleClientRequest** method instead of **QueryNodeRequest**.Now, after some digging, I learned that SignalR does not handle polymorphism by default (or message does not get serialized/deserialized properly, to type I would expect - in this case **QueryNodeRequest** which inherits from **HubRequestMessageBase**).

My question is : Is there any possibility to accomplish this somehow utilizing JsonSerializer settings on both client and server? Note that I already tried following code (and also some variants) without any success (on the server):

```
GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.Register(typeof(JsonSerializer),
                                                () => JsonSerializer.Create(new JsonSerializerSettings
                                                {
                                                    TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All
                                                }));
```

Thanks in advance!

Cheers,
Civa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to implement [`IParameterResolver`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.signalr.hubs.iparameterresolver(v=vs.118).aspx) and register it. The default [parameter resolver](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core/Hubs/Lookup/DefaultParameterResolver.cs) simply converts `JValues` to target parameter types.

Comment: Hello Pawel, thank you very much for the answer, I will try this one and let you know as soon as possible.

Comment: Unfortunately, this method didn't solve my problem since IJsonValue already contains data type of interest I'm expecting : `{"$type":"Zenith.Network.Api.Messages.QueryNodeRequest, Zenith.Network.Api",
 ...<Rest of JSON omitted for brevity>
}` and I simply couldn't convert it back to HubRequestMessageBase (as value in ParameterType).I ended up writing separate methods per request type and it is working as expected.However, I will mark your response as accepted since this is one way to deal with polymorphic message types and perhaps someone will find it useful.

Answer (score 1):

I have been able to solve this.

The root cause of the issue is this line in the signalr code base
https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core/Json/JRawValue.cs#L28
where signalr uses a default serializer and does not let you inject your own.

My solution is to bypass that serializer by making the type of my parameter JObject
and then turing that JObject into my concrete type in the hub itself by using a customized instance of the serializer, and a JTokenReader based on the JObject

My Hub Method (note that ClientCommand is an abstract base class for all my possible commands)

```
public async Task DispatchCommand(Envelope envelope)
{
    var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
                   {
                       TypeNameAssemblyFormatHandling = TypeNameAssemblyFormatHandling.Simple,
                       TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects
                   };
    var serializer = JsonSerializer.Create(settings);
    var c = (ClientCommand) serializer.Deserialize(new JTokenReader(envelope.Command), typeof(ClientCommand));

    await commandDispatcher.SendCommand(c);
}
```

The Envelope type

```
public sealed class Envelope
{
    public JObject Command { get; set; }
}
```

By using TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects on the JsonSerializer all I need to do is include the $type property in my object that I send from the client.

Comment: I know this is an old issue but thanks a lot for the answer StocksR, well spotted, it is definitelly helpful. Cheers!